# call R's error function from Fortran

Tags: r, fortran, call

How do I call R's built-in functions 'error' and 'warning' from Fortran? It was straight forward to do from C, but if I use something like

```
call error('an error occured')
```

in my Fortran code, the dynamic library won't load because of "undefined symbol: error_". I can see that the R CMD SHLIB command links with -lR, so what else would be needed? Do they maybe have a different name when called from Fortran?

Answer (score 1):

According to the [Writing R Extensions](http://cran.r-project.org/doc/manuals/r-release/R-exts.html#Error-handling-from-FORTRAN) manual,

> *There are two interface function provided to call error and warning from FORTRAN code, in each case with a simple character string argument. They are defined as:*

```
subroutine rexit(message)
subroutine rwarn(message)
```

> *Messages of more than 255 characters are truncated, with a warning.*